# AndroidRuntime looking for ndk so files at wrong path

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using JNI c++ files to store strings in encrypted format.

**Below is my CMakelists.txt :**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library ( native-lib SHARED native-lib.cpp boot-lib.cpp call-lib.cpp state-lib.cpp cap- 
lib.cpp manage-lib.cpp on-lib.cpp service-lib.cpp network-lib.cpp )
find_library ( log-lib log )
target_link_libraries( native-lib ${log-lib} )
```

**From my class named CallStateService.java :**

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("state-lib");
}
```

I am loading `state-lib` library and it loads well. Project Cleans good. Project Rebuilds good.

**When i run it over emulator gets crash :**

```
02-10 15:12:11.848 3433-3433/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mycompany.app.myapp, PID: 3433
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.app.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycompany.app.myapp-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.mycompany.app.myapp-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libstate-lib.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
    at com.mycompany.app.myapp.CallStateService.<clinit>(CallStateService.java:37)
```

**What my concerns are :**

- As per `logcat` which showing `couldn't find "libstate-lib.so"` is not the part of project nor i am having such file in the project named `libstate-lib.cpp.`
- My project name is `com.mycompany.app.myapp` then in runtime why it is looking for `com.mycompany.app.myapp-1/`
- Also it is looking for `nativeLibraryDirectories` within `nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycompany.app.myapp-1/lib/x86` instead of `nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycompany.app.myapp/lib/x86`

**What i have tried so far :** 
 - Changed the location of CMakelists.txt file many times and changed
   the paths of linked .cpp files and clean, build and rebuild.
 - Invalidated caches and restarted studio.
 - Changed the app version in build.gradle
 - Cleared app data in emulator and uninstalled and restrted emulator many times and then tried running over it again

I hope someone will help me. Thank you in advance and any help will be appreciated.